# Assignment of objects in C++

Tags: c++, object, variable-assignment, assign

To contextualize my question, I'm using a Matrix class with the following definitions:

```
Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int); // matrix of the given dimension full of zeroes
Matrix(Matrix*); // creates a new matrix from another one
int &operator()(int, int);  // used to access the matrix
int **matrix; // the matrix
```

Now take these two code snippets:

First:

```
Matrix test(4,4);
Matrix ptr = test;
ptr(0,0) = 95;
```

Second:

```
Matrix test(4,4);
Matrix *ptr = &test;
(*ptr)(0,0) = 95;
```

Both codes have the same effect, the element in the (0,0) position receives 95 (The first snippet is very similar to Java, the reason which led me to ask this question).
The question is, are both ways correctly making the assignment of the object?

Comment: I think you will find that they are not both the same...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a little complicated.

Consider this simple class:

```
class Thing1
{
public:
  int n;
}
```

Now we try the first experiment:

```
Thing1 A;
A.n = 5;

Thing1 B = A;
B.n = 7;

cout << A.n << " " << B.n << endl;
```

The result is "5 7". `A` and `B` are two separate, independent objects. Changing one doesn't change the other.

Second experiment:

```
Thing1 *p = &A;
p->n = 9;

cout << A.n << " " << p->n << endl;
```

The result is "9 9"; `p` is a pointer to `A`, so `A.n` and `p->n` are the same thing.

Now things get complicated:

```
class Thing2
{
public:
  int *p;
};

...
Thing2 A;
A.p = new int(2);

Thing2 B = A;
*(B.p) = 4;

cout << *(A.p) << " " << *(B.p) << endl;
```

Now the result is "4 4". The assignment `B = A` copied the *pointer*, so although `A` and `B` are two different objects, their pointers point to the same int. This is a **shallow copy**. In general, if you want to make a **deep copy** (that is, each Thing points to an int of its own) you must either do it by hand or give the class an *assignment operator* which will handle it. Since your `Matrix` class doesn't have an explicit assignment operator, the compiler gives it the default-- which is a shallow copy. That's why, in your first snippet, both matrices appear to be changed.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @AlisherKassymov, for pointing out that declarations of the form `Thing A=B;` use the *copy constructor,* not the *assignment operator.* So for the solution to work in the above code, the copy constructor must make a deep copy. (Note that if the copy constructor does it, you almost certainly want the assignment operator to do it too (see the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)))). Also note that if these functions get complicated, it makes sense to simply have the copy constructor invoke the assignment operator.)

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks for the clear explanation of the concepts involved (shallow copy and deep copy).

Comment: I don’t think that this is correct. Making an assignment operator overload will not change the result in this case. This is a copy constructor. In order to make an assignment operator to work, you firstly need to construct the object and then use = to copy another object

Comment: @AlisherKassymov: **You're right, thank you.** I forgot that `Thing A=B;` uses the copy constructor, not the assignment operator (although the copy ctor is often implemented in terms of op=), and didn't test my solution far enough. I'll edit.

Comment: @Beta So suppose I typed `Thing2 B; B=A;` Do both objects' pointer point to the same memory address?

Comment: @user148469: Yes. If you want an assignment operator that makes a deep copy, you must write it yourself.

Comment: Uh...no? For @Terrarium's question, `B` and `A` are different objects. The compiler-provided assignment operator (and copy constructors) *will* copy the members. (They are sometimes called shallow because they don't dereference the pointers, but they work fine if we don't have dynamic data.)  Do you agree?

Comment: @flow2k: I do not agree. You have misread the text above.

Comment: @Beta Upon a rereading of Terrarium's question, I think it can also be interpreted to mean `*p` field. Is that what you understood when you initially answered the question? Frankly, I think the wording in the question is a bit ambiguous. But I don't think I said anything incorrect after possibly "Uh...no?".

Answer (score 5):

These two are not equal.

**The first snippet**

`Matrix test`, with is full content is COPIED into `Matrix ptr`.
When you work with `ptr` later, you only change the copy, not the original `Matrix test`.

**The second snippet**

The address of `Matrix test` is put into the pointer `Matrix *ptr`.
The pointer now holds the address of `test`.
When you write `(*ptr)`, you dereference the pointer and work with the value of the original `test`.

**In Java**

In java, all objects are kindof pointers (primitives like `int` are not). When you assign one object to another there, the default is to only overwrite the pointer value. Works like your second example.

Comment: I'm finding it strange, using the first snippet both of them are being changed, i.e. the element in position (0,0) is set to 95.

Comment: Do you have a pointer inside the Matrix-class which points to the stored data? When you copy an object like this, any pointers inside the class are also copied and will point to the same values in the new class.

Answer (score 3):

The first copies that value of `test` into `ptr`.
The second sets ptr to be a pointer to the address of `test`

These two actions are not the same. In the first case, `ptr` will have the same value as `test`, but they are in them selves two distinct copies of that data, so that your assignment of `ptr(0,0) = 95;` will not set `test(0, 0)`.

In the second instance however, `ptr` points to the address of `test`, so that the dereference of `ptr` *is* test. Thus, when you set the value here, you are actually setting the value of `test(0, 0)` as well.

This is trivially verifyable with a program such as this:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test{
public:
    int i;
};

int main(){
    Test c;
    c.i = 1;

    Test d = c;
    d.i = 2;
    std::cout << "Value: " << c.i << "\n";

    Test* e = &c;
    (*e).i = 2;
    std::cout << "Pointer: " << c.i << "\n";
}
```

Of course, if you dynamically allocate your Matrix (new) then when you copy the value as per your first example, the pointer to the data is also copied, so when you set the new data, it appears to be equal to the second example.

Comment: My mistake was in assuming that values being copied were new values, but is the pointer to the data that is copied. Thanks for the clear answer the code example Quirliom, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of Java behavior in this case is expressed using C++ *references*

```
Matrix test(4,4);
Matrix &ptr = test;
ptr(0,0) = 95;
```

This code indeed does the same thing as the pointer version, i.e. it modifies the original `test` object.

Your first code sample formally creates a *copy* of the original object and then modifies that copy. However, your `Matrix` class appears to be a multi-level object that owns some lower-level memory (`matrix` pointer). If your `Matrix` class copy constructor implements shallow-copying logic (i.e. it shares the lower-level matrix data with the original object instead of deep-copying it), then modifying the copy will appear to modify the original object as well. Whether this behavior is correct or incorrect depends on your intent.

In your comments you mentioned that the first code also appears to modify the original object. This immediately means that your class in fact implements shallow-copying logic. And it looks like it is not an intended part of your design. Apparently you forgot to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) when you were implementing your `Matrix` class.